# How do I convert a string date saved in seperate variables to a date using asp.net vb? The month variable is written out in text format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

The data that I have to convert is written as the separate variables "Month", "Day", and "Year".

The data I need to convert for example is:
Month is "July"
Day is "21"
Year is "2013"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Combine it and use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
Dim dtStr = String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", month, day, year)
Dim dt = Date.ParseExact(dtStr, "MMMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Also have a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

If you don't know if the data is valid you should use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h9b85w22.aspx):

```
Dim dt As DateTime
If Date.TryParseExact(dtStr, "MMMM dd yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, dt) Then
    Console.Write("Date is: " & dt.ToShortDateString())
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first put the date into a string so

```
Dim dateString as string = string.format({0} {1} {2}, day, month, year)
```

Where day, month, year reference the variables holding the date values.

Then try

```
Dim result as DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dateString)
```